# Losing Weight ASAP but in the right way

Tags: weight-loss

Okay, to start off, my stats:

> Age : 22
>   Height : 172cm
>   Weight : 95kg

I just want to lose wieght in the most effective way. Currently I'm working out (at least 3-4 times a week). I skip meals every night.

I need advice on how to do this in the fastest but right way.

Is what i'm doing correct? If not, what are the proper methods?

Also.. can you give me targets? (example, how many weight should one loss in a week/month)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, if you need to lose weight, don't plan on doing it quickly as that approach typically ends in yo-yo dieting  where you lose then gain it all back.  Rather, plan on a change in lifestyle that includes sensible eating and exercise for the **long term**.  Losing more than 1 to 2 pounds per week can be excessive and result in muscle loss as well.

Answer (score 1):

in a first time, we cannot tell you how much you can / should loss in a week / month, that depend of many variables.

After that, one of the best way is this :

- Remove sodas of your alimentation.
- Remove all candy or sweet bar if there is.
- Restrict the sugar intake (remind that, all things containing flour, is a glucose intake, pasta and rice too)
- Privilegied, sometimes, wholemeal bread (we need some glucide anyway, and slow sugar is good too bring all along the day some glucide, you can eat wholemeal bread in the morning, and no more)
- Peanut butter without added sugar is nice too.
- Meat one time a day, or one time for two day if you can have some products to bring you the protein intake..
- Salads with fish (with tuna) is really good, personally i love that (and with olive oil is interesting)
- If you can, some sardines or mackerel is good too for protein intake
- Eat vegetables and fruits.

Try to don't skip meal but the breakfast if you have just sweet things, otherwise you can eat cottage cheese (i've forgot, this is really good to eat)
and some fruits.